# Differences between these two throttle implementations

Tags: javascript, throttling

Approach one:

```
function throttle(func, timeMs) {
  let lastTime = 0;
  return function() {
      const now = new Date();
      if (now - lastTime >= timeMs) {
          func();
          lastTime = now;
      }
  };
}
```

Approach two:

```
function throttle(func, timeMs) {
    let waiting = false;
    return function() {
        if (!waiting) {
            func();
            waiting = true;
            setTimeout(() => {
                waiting = false;
            }, timeMs);
        }
    }
}
```

One uses the timestamp to keep track of the call while the other uses timeout. Is one better than the other?

Comment: Both look perfectly reasonable to me

Comment: For this problem, both are ok, but when it become more complicated, with large time frames, I prefer using 1/, epoch and test. SetTimeout is often a source of ui frame freezes on slow machines and phones.

Comment: Approach #1 is superior because it doesn't need to schedule a timer that might a) be inaccurate b) unnecessary/inefficient if there is no further call c) keep the event loop busy

Comment: Also, the example 2/ can create memory leaks, it's important to pass the timeout in a variable, and then clear it each round with `clearTimeout()`. If `func()` takes longer than the timeout, this is where the freezes might comes if the last timeout is not cleared^ Also always use `requestAnimationFrame()` for each redraw, when looping like that. I had upvoted and reopen the question.

Comment: @NVRM I don't see any memory leak from #2. There's always at most one active timeout per throttled function. It doesn't schedule new timeouts while it's `waiting`, it doesn't need to clear previous ones.

Comment: A problem that both implementations have is they're not re-entrant, i.e. if `func` calls the function returned by `throttle` it will recurse.